# Is there any way to automate call recording in microsoft teams app and then creating its transcript and saving it to the system using teams app?

Tags: automation, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, speech-to-text, power-automate-custom-connector

I tried using the power automate to create a flow for this but unfortunately we cannot create a flow for call recording and making transcript and saving it to system using teams app. Need help for this issue???

Comment: You can use Graph API to create a meeting and then use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-callrecords) subscription to address this issue.

Comment: @Amul - Does the above helped you moving forward?